# 'This' is not the same in constructor and inherited constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have this simple inheritance pattern:

```
function Emitter() {
    this.dis1 = this;
};

function Person() {
    this.dis2 = this;
};
Person.prototype = new Emitter();
var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();

console.log(p1.dis1 === p2.dis1); //true - why?
console.log(p1.dis2 === p2.dis2); //false
```

Why are dis1 of separate objects the same? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Looking at the code, you're only creating a single emitter, but two person objects. What would be your expected result?

Comment: I would like p1.dis1 and p2.dis1 to be different

Comment: You want them to be different ? But to be what ?

Comment: Then move dis1 into Person. You've made the Person prototype inherit from Emitter. Hence, the two objects share the same property.

Comment: A prototype is a single _object_ (the one you created explicitly), not a _class_ of which an instance is created for each object using it as a prototype. Setting a prototype is not the same as inheritance in - for example - Java or C++.

Comment: As your example doesn't make any sense, it's hard to suggest anything useful. Could you tell what's the real goal ?

Comment: The real goal is for Emitter to have listerers, so I could add a listener to the person instance, not shared by persons.

Comment: Please see [Object|Prototype](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#object.prototype) at JSGarden.

Comment: [Do not use `new` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A note on how the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) works:

```
Foo = function(){};
Foo.prototype;

var bar = new Foo();
```

What happens on the last line is a new object is created which inherits from `Foo.prototype` and then the code in the `Foo` function is executed with `this` being that new object. Then bar is initialized to that new object.

---

Your inheritance model has several flaws and you have uncovered one of them. All the flaws stem from this line of code:

```
Person.prototype = new Emitter();
```

This line says that the object all Person instances inherit from is an instance of Emitter (the instance of Emitter created there).

`p1.dist1` looks up the dist1 property on the prototype chain. First it looks in `p1` to see if it has the `dist1` property and it does not. Next it looks in `p1.[[Prototype]]` which was initialized to `Person.prototype` where it does find the `dist1` property and it's value is `Person.prototype` (the one instance of Emitter mentioned above).

`p1.dist` does the same thing, but the property is found in `p1` and it is equal to `p1`.

The same thing happens with `p2`, `p2.dist1` being the same instance of Emitter while `p2.dist2` being equal to `p2`.

---

A way to do inheritance and avoid all these problems would be:

```
function Emitter() {
    this.dis1 = this;
};

function Person() {
    Emitter.call(this); // calls the parent constructor.
    this.dis2 = this;
};
Person.prototype = Object.create(Emitter.prototype); // you don't even use this line

var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();
```

In this model, `p1.dist1 === p1` and `p1.dist2 === p1`, `p2.dist1 === p2` and `p2.dist2 === p2`. What happens here is that the code in the Emitter constructor is called with this being the new Person object being created. So when you say in the Emitter constructor `this.dis1 = this`, `this` is actually `p1` or `p2`.

The line with the prototype is not used in this example, but it does other cool things you might want:

- Methods and properties declared on Emitter.prottoype will be available for p1 and p2
- `p1 instanceof Emitter` will be true.

You can find this model also used on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

The `dis1` property is [looked up in the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

As it's not present in p1 or p2, it's looked up in the prototype, which is the object you created with `new Emitter()`. That's the reason why you have the same value.

The prototypal model in JavaScript is very different from the inheritance model you have in other languages like Java. Be careful not to try to emulate Java or C++ designs in JavaScript : that always lead to bad ones.

Now, suppose you want to have an object at the Emitter level and different for each Person instance, then the simplest solution might be to initialize the values on demand or using a specific function (you might use a convention to name it `initialize` and then override it).

Example with on demand initialization :

```
function Emitter() {
}
Emitter.prototype.register = function(thing){
  if (!this.listeners) {
      this.listeners = []; 
  }
  this.listeners.push(thing);
}

function Person() {
}
Person.prototype = new Emitter();
```

In fact the best solution here would probably, as often in real OOP languages, to [prefer composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and to simply set the emitter as a property of the person.

Comment: My goal is for Emitter to have listerers, so I could add a listener to the person instance, not shared by persons

Comment: @RobFox The simplest solution would be to initialize the properties you need at the Emitter level not in the constructor but when you need them (the first time).

Answer (score 1):

As dystroy already mentioned, `dis1` gets looked up in the prototype chain. If you want to have different `dis1`s for different `Person`s, you can use the following pattern.

```
function Emitter() {
    this.dis1 = this;
};

function Person() {
    Emitter.call(this);
    this.dis2 = this;
};
Person.prototype = Object.create(Emitter.prototype);
var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();

console.log(p1.dis1 === p2.dis1); //false
console.log(p1.dis2 === p2.dis2); //false
```

Note that you have to call `Emitter` inside the `Person` constructor, while providing `this` as current context. Creating a new Person will now create an object that contains all the (local) properties of `Person` as well as all the (local) properties of `Emitter` in a flat hierarchy:

```
{
    dis1: Person,
    dis2: Person
}
```

You also can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to realize prototype inheritance. This has the advantage, that you don't actually call the `Emitter` constructor and thereby you don't get "local" properties like `dis1` to be inside the prototype object.